# What's wrong with my use of plugin_url()?

Tags: functions, plugins-url

I keep getting the following message in the browser `Fatal error: Call to undefined function plugin_url() in`

My code at present:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_script', 'load_jquery2' );
function load_jquery2() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );    }  


function add_my_css_and_my_js_files(){
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-validate-min', plugin_url('/activate/jquery_validate_min.js', __FILE__ ) );
 }
  add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', "add_my_css_and_my_js_files");
```

The plugin is in a folder called 'activate' & the JS is in that folder directly, not a sub folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function add_my_css_and_my_js_files(){
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-validate-min', plugins_url('activate/jquery_validate_min.js', __FILE__ ) );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', "add_my_css_and_my_js_files");
```

1. You need to use the `plugins_url()` function (you are missing the
   **s** at the end of *plugins*).
2. Reference the location of the script file with the relative path.  Meaning the path should be `activate/jquery_validate_min.js`.

Comment: yeah, you are right. did not see the additional slash.

Answer (score 2):

The function you are looking for is called `plugins_url()` ([ref](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url)), with the additional s. Should be fine afterwards.